# In php, Onclick event in a function with regular expression

Tags: javascript, php

I'd like to perform the following function in php.

""If there is URL format in a text, the URL becomes link.
When the link of the URL is clicked, onclick event is called.
Then the alert from the onclick event generates. ""

I am writing down the following code, but it doesn't work well.

Could you tell me how to solve this ploblem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">

<title>test</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

function makeLink($value) {
    return mb_ereg_replace("(https?)(://[[a-zA-Z0-9]\+\$\;\?\.%,!#~*/:@&=_-]+)", '<a href="#" onclick="alert($value);">\1\2</a>' , $value);
}

$text = 'HELLO!! http://google.com';

echo makeLink($text);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want `'<a href="#" onclick="alert('.$value.');">\1\2</a>'`

Depending on the version of php, there are a few ways to use variables within strings. In your case, you are just writing the string `$value`, not using the variable.

What I did is end the string (with the single quote) then use dots `.` to concatenate the variable, then continue the string (single quotes again).

If using double quotes, you can do this:

```
$foo = 'code';
echo "this $foo works"; //will echo "this code works"
```

There is also much else wrong with your code. It's worth noting that using "onclick" in your html has never been a good practice and just serves to make your code even more confusing. The proper modern approach to communicating between javascript and php is through ajax, but if you must take this approach, at least put your javascript into `<script>` tag and at the beginning of that tag, get the information you need into javascript variable. Altogether, like this:

var value = '';
//etc

So, remove that whole regex thing altogether...according to your example here, it's useless and bloated.

```
<?php
  $text = 'HELLO!! http://google.com';
  $linkId = 'my-link';
  echo '<a href="#" id="'.$linkId.'">12</a>';
?>

<script>
  var text = '<?php echo $text; ?>';
  var linkId = '<?php echo $linkId; ?>';
  var linkElem = document.getElementById(linkId);
  linkElem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    myFunction(text);
  });
  function myFunction(text) {
    alert(text);
  }
</script>
```

If you did this, it would at least be better, but this whole approach is still very flawed. I recommend learning about separation of concerns and SOLID principles. This is all global, hard to read, hard to debug, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand what you say. However, It doesn't still work with your method. I think there is another problem.

Comment: Apologies, there is a lot wrong with your code. See my updated answer. @szakira

Comment: @szakira Is my answer not helpful? If it is, could you kindly accept it using the checkmark to the left of the answer? This also will reward you some reputation points.